# Consider all characters for URL Encode, post data, complete solution iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-encoding

I am sending the data to a server in post body. For which I had used the following code from the [Encoding URL Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html).

```
CFStringRef encodedString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    originalString,
    NULL,
    CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Later on I forgot to add one more character in the list which was "’" , a apostrophe. I don't how many character's to add.

Also, if there are some special character's to be submitted to a server with application/x-www-form-urlencoded, what could be a best and stable solution.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking a generic solution , to handle all character's to be encoded, which sending the post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are missing `%` on your string.

There is also another solution you can try:

```
NSString *encodedURL = [rawURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Good catch. The solution which you recommend is a generic one, as I don't see any list of specific character's to be mentioned here.

Comment: generally `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` handles everything, every character that needs to be encoded. The only question here is what encoding you should use. In this case, UTF8.